# Recursively dumping the content of a file located in different folders

Tags: bash

Still being a newbie with bash-programming I am fighting with another task I got. A specific file called ".dump" (yes, with a dot in the beginning) is located in each folder and always contains three numbers. I need to dump the third number in a variable in case it is greater than 1000 and then print this and the folder name locating the number. So the outcome should look like this:

```
"/dir1/ 1245" 
"/dir1/subdir1/ 3434"
"/dir1/subdir2/ 10003"
"/dir1/subdir2/subsubdir3/ 4123" 
"/dir2/ 45440"
```

`(without "" and each of them in a new line (not sure, why it is not shown correctly here))`

I was playing around with `awk`, `find` and `while`, but the results are that bad that I do not wanna post them here, which I hope is understood. So any code snippet helping is appreciated.

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? It has several features that simplify doing this purely in shell.

Answer (score 1):

This could be cleaned up, but should work:

```
find /dir1 /dir2 -name .dump -exec sh -c 'k=$(awk "\$3 > 1000{print \$3; exit 1}" $0) ||
    echo ${0%.dump} $k ' {} \;
```

(I'm assuming that all three numbers in your .dump files appear on one line.  The awk will need to be modified if the input is in a different format.)

Comment: Thanks so far. However dir1 and dir2 are not the only directories. There are just thousands of them with different names. I tried to simplify things, but it looks I hereby caused some confusion, for which I apologize.

Comment: If all of your directories share a common parent, just pass the path to the parent as the first argument to find.  It will do a recursive descent.